# Could not install tymon/jwt-aut in Laravel 5.2.39

Tags: php, laravel-5, jwt

I try to install tymon/jwt-aut in fresh Laravel 5.2.39

```
composer require tymon/jwt-aut
```

I'm get response:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                        
Could not find package tymon/jwt-aut at any version for your 
minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be 
`composer require tymon/jwt-auth`

You are missing an `h`

https://packagist.org/packages/tymon/jwt-auth